# launch failed. Binary not found

Tags: c++, eclipse

I am trying to get eclipse set up to work with C++, however when I try to run a basic program I get the error: `Launch failed. Binary not found`

Also this prints to the console:

```
Configuration failed with error
(Cannot run program "sh": Launching failed)
```

This is the path that I have set:

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_01\bin;C:\msys\1.0\bin;C:\mingw\bin;`

All help will be appreciated.

Comment: look for eclipse CDT windows on the web.

Answer (score 3):

For Windows:

```
Project / Properties / C/C++ Build / Settings /Binary parsers:
```

Turn on "`PE Windows Parser`"

Then, build it (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>) before running/debugging

```
project->build project
```

Comment: In the case of Linux, I checked GNU elf parser and Mach O 64 parser, then the error disappeared.